Suggestion not showing up for input
I am trying to learn react by practising a simple problem.
I followed the below youtube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsvybgZTryo&list=PLKhlp2qtUcSZiWKJTi5-5r6IRdHhxP9ZU&index=17
but when I search for an item the suggestions are not coming, I debugged by putting console, still console not printing
can you let me know what is the issue, providing the code snippet and stackblitz below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-zt8wiu?file=src%2FApp.jsx,src%2FApp.css,src%2Fcomponents%2Fpill.jsx&terminal=dev
<ul className="suggestions-list">
                {suggestions?.users?.map((user, index) => {
                  console.log('slectedUserSet --->', slectedUserSet);
                  return slectedUserSet.has(user.email) ? (
                    // current user which we selected
                    <li key={user.email} onClick={() => handleSelectUser(user)}>
                      <img
                        src={user.image}
                        alt={`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`}
                      />
                      <span>
                        ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}
                      </span>
                    </li>
                  ) : (
                    <></>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>


App.jsx:
line 23, the promise chain is missing a return
line 78, there is a typo.

thanks for your response I am able to fix the typo in the line number 78, but not able to fix the line number 23,. So confusing, can you please update in the stackblitz @user3309300

fetch(https://dummyjson.com/users/search?q=${searchTerm})
.then((res) => {
return res.json();
})
